# Django project set up with Apache2 - i want to access it through I.P/application_name/

Tags: django, apache, apache2

Hi I want to set up my django project to be access through apache2 by I.P/application_name/

So "192.0.0.0/app/" (Ip being an example)

Here is my 000-default.conf file in etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess HTSv2 python-home=/home/django/config/env python-path=/usr/local/django/app
    WSGIProcessGroup HTSv2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/app/application/wsgi.py

    <Directory  /usr/local/django/app/application>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /usr/local/django/app/static/

    <Directory /usr/local/django/app/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/local/django/app>
            Deny from all
            Allow from ...
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I change the line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/app/application/wsgi.py
```

to

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app/ /usr/local/django/app/application/wsgi.py
```

I can access the home page of my application by 192.0.0.0/app/

However when I click on any buttons, obviously does not keep to this, so for example going to page1, does not go to  192.0.0.0/app/page1, it goes to  192.0.0.0/page1

How can I configure apache2 to do this? The reason I want to do this is so I can host multiple projects on the same server, so the root of 1 project is  192.0.0.0/app1/ and then the root of the other is  192.0.0.0/app2/ etc...

Comment: You need to give an example of the template containing your "buttons". How are you outputting the URLs there? Are you using the `{% url %}` tag?

Comment: I have mostly hardcoded them, if I use the {% url %} tag will this mean that when I use alias, the /app/ bit of the url will stay? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's one of the main points of using it; it works out the full path, taking into account the hosting prefix.

Comment: Great thank you, I will change the href in my navbar and use this